# Strange artifact ·10^6 in my plot. Where does it come from how do I get rid of it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{146,200,180}
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{124,206,89}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar, xmin=0,
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
    tickwidth         = 0pt,
    width=12cm, height=3.5cm, enlarge y limits=0.5,
    symbolic y coords={a,b},
    ytick=data,
    bar shift=0pt,
    y dir=reverse,
    xtick={1, 500000, 1000000},
    xticklabels={0, 5 min, 10 min},
]


\addplot+[color1, forget plot]    coordinates { (600000,a) };

\addplot+[color2, forget plot]    coordinates { (1020000,b) };
\addplot+[white, forget plot] coordinates { (600000,b) };
\addplot [white, forget plot] coordinates { (600000,b) };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Resulting in the following plot:
[image]

Notice the:
[image]

Where does it come from? How do I get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: this is not artifact but scale factor for your x axis. real values for tick you cover with own definition of xtick labels. remove `xticklabels={0, 5 min, 10 min},` and see, what you will obtain.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `scaled x ticks=false` to get rid of the `\cdot 10^{6}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{146,200,180}
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{124,206,89}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar, xmin=0,
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
    tickwidth         = 0pt,
    width=12cm, height=3.5cm, enlarge y limits=0.5,
    symbolic y coords={a,b},
    ytick=data,
    bar shift=0pt,
    y dir=reverse,
    xtick={1, 500000, 1000000},
    xticklabels={0, 5 min, 10 min},
    scaled x ticks=false
]


\addplot+[color1, forget plot]    coordinates { (600000,a) };

\addplot+[color2, forget plot]    coordinates { (1020000,b) };
\addplot+[white, forget plot] coordinates { (600000,b) };
\addplot [white, forget plot] coordinates { (600000,b) };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```